# Luego de hacer la consulta a la base de datos, la interfaz muestra en pantalla n-1 registros

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo consultas a BD desde mi portal, y cuando en la DB tengo más de 1 usuario con los mismos datos mi búsqueda me muestra n-1 usuarios: por ejemplo si tengo 5 usuarios con el mismo nombre la búsqueda me muestra 4 registros con la información que busco, pero si en mi BD solo tengo un usuario y hago la consulta, sí lo encuentra pero no lo despliega en pantalla.

Muestro el código con el cual hago esto:

```html
<form action="consulta_usuario.php" method="POST" class="formulariotabla2 opaco">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>TABLA DE CLIENTES</legend>
        <TABLE class="tabla" BORDER>
            <TR>
                <TH>Nombre</TH> <TH>Apellido Paterno</TH> <TH>Apellido Materno</TH> <TH>Email</TH>
                <TH>Hospital</TH> <TH>Teléfono</TH> <TH>Extensión</TH> <TH>Celular</TH>
                <TH>Fecha de Nacimineto</TH> <TH>Horario Inicio</TH>
                <TH>Horario Fin</TH> <TH>Cargo</TH>  <TH>Dirección</TH>
            </TR>
            <?php
                while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
                {
             ?>    
                    <TR>
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['nombre_cliente'];?></TD> 
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['apellido_paterno_cliente'];?></TD>
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['apellido_materno_cliente'];?></TD>
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['correo'];?></TD>
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['hospital'];?></TD>
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['telefono'];?></TD> 
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['extension'];?></TD>
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['celular'];?></TD>
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['fecha_nacimineto'];?></TD>
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['horario_disponible_inicio'];?></TD>
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['horario_disponible_ifin'];?></TD> 
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['cargo'];?></TD>
                        <TD><?php echo $mostrar['direccion_hosp'];?></TD>
                    </TR>
            <?php
                }
                mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>    
        </TABLE>
        <div class="grid3">
        <a  href="consulta_clientes.php?<?php echo "variable1=$nombre_vendedor"?>" class="botton w-sm-100 navegacion-principal contenedor" >REGRESAR</a>    
        <a  href="modificar_clientes.php?<?php echo "variable1=$nombre_vendedor"?>" class="botton w-sm-100 navegacion-principal contenedor" >MODIFICAR</a> 
        </div>
```

En la siguiente imagen hago la consulta de un usuario que está registrado en distintos lugares, y en mi base de datos tengo el usuario con 3 ubicaciones distintas, y solo me muestra 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando hago la búsqueda cuando solo tengo un usuario sí lo encuentra pero no lo muestra.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No estaría demás que muestres la consulta en cuestión (aunque parece ser que el problema está en el código php).

Comment: esto ocurre por que dependiendo de la cantidad de registros encontrados puedes tener un objeto de arrays o un objeto de un único registro...

Comment: para ir depurando basta con que hagas debug de lo que devuelve la consulta y como la devuelve ... dependiendo de esto tendrás distintas formas de acceder a esa data...

Comment: yo realice un echo antes del while cuando busco un solo registro y si están los datos en la variable, pero el problema es que no entra al ciclo while, y no se como solucionarlo

Comment: Hola. Faltan datos en tu pregunta. No se ve cómo obtienes `$resultado`, en ese contexto podrías haber aplicado un `fetch` que habrá movido una fila en el puntero... Tampoco se ve qué consulta SQL estás mandando, puede que esa consulta tenga un `GROUP BY`. Pulsa en [edit] y muestra el contexto completo de obtención de datos.

Comment: Gracias por los cometarios, ya puse el código completo, espero puedan apoyarme